# Why Numbers are getting printed in the form like "12-256" , "13-256" rather than 12,13 etc.?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I'm solving one of the algorithms problem from university to implemet queue using stacks.
I've got my logic right i guess but the numbers are getting printed in the form of **12-256**, **13-256**, **14-256** instead of **12**,**13**,**14**.

Here's my **C++** Code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack{

private:
    int arr[200];
    int tos = -1;

public:

    bool empty(){
        return (tos == -1)?true:false;
    }

    void push(int element){
        arr[++tos] = element;
    }

    int pop(){
        return arr[tos--];
    }

    void show(){
        if(tos == -1){
            cout<<"stack empty";
        }else{
            for(int i=tos;i>0;i--)
                cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
        }
    }

};


class Queue{

private:
    Stack s1,s2;


public:
    void enQueue(int x){

        //just using s1 to add new elements
        s1.push(x);
    }

    int deQueue(){

        if(s1.empty())
            throw 'e';

        else{
            int e;
            while(!s1.empty()){
                e = s1.pop();
                s2.push(e);
            }

            cout<<"\nelement to be removed:"<<s2.pop();

            if(s2.empty())
                throw 'f';

            else{
                int e;
                while(!s2.empty()){
                    e = s2.pop();
                    s1.push(e);
                }
            }
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    try{
        Queue q1;
        q1.enQueue(12);
        q1.enQueue(13);
        q1.enQueue(14);
        q1.enQueue(15);

        cout<<q1.deQueue();
        cout<<q1.deQueue();
        cout<<q1.deQueue();
        cout<<q1.deQueue();
    }catch(char c){
        cout<<"\nstack empty!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here's my Output.]

I'm basically a Python Guy so i'm not able to figure out what's wrong with this code.

I'm new to C++, so please guide me through this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `deQueue` doesn't return anything.

Comment: don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: If you compiled with warnings enabled and heeded them, you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deQueue` suffers from the following problems.

1. It doesn't return anything.
2. It's OK for `s2` to be empty after its top has been popped.

Here's an updated version that should work.

```
int deQueue(){

   if(s1.empty())
      throw 'e';

   int e;
   while(!s1.empty()){
      e = s1.pop();
      s2.push(e);
   }

   int ret = s2.pop();
   cout<<"\nelement dequeued:"<< ret;

   // This is not correct.
   // It's OK for s2 to be empty after its top has been popped.
   // if(s2.empty())
   //    throw 'f';

   while(!s2.empty()){
      e = s2.pop();
      s1.push(e);
   }

   return ret;
}
```

#### Suggestion for further improvement

`Queue` does not need two `Stack` objects as member variables. `s2` can be a function local variable in `deQueue`.

```
class Queue
{
    private:

      Stack s;

   ...
};
```

If you decide to make that change, you'll have to update `enQueue` and `deQueue` accordingly.